# control structure + Python

Tags: python, error-handling, conditional-statements, control-structure

the following is an exercise on "Control Structures".

I am sure it can be done in many different ways and that my (incomplete) solution is far from ELEGANT.

At the moment I can include all the "cases" except when a string includes one or more consecutive dots "..." in which case it should print "Password" insted it currently print "Transaction".

please see text and code below and thanks much in advance for looking into it.

exercise:
Imagine you're writing a cash register application. To make
interaction easier on the user, it doesn't have separate
areas for passwords, PIN numbers, or cash totals --
instead, it looks at what the cashier enters and infers
whether it's their PIN number, their password, or the cash
total for a transaction.

The register makes this decision with the following rules:

- If the cashier entered only digits, then it's a PIN
  number.
- If the cashier entered a decimal number, then it's the
  transaction amount.
- If the cashier entered anything else, then it's their
  password.

Write a function named interpretCashier. interpretCashier
should take one parameter as input, which will always be
a string initially.

If the string entered represents a PIN number, return
"PIN".
If the string entered represents a transaction amount,
return "Transaction".
If the string entered represents a password, return
"Password".

code:

```
**symbols = ["£", "$", "%", "&", "A", "a", "b", "z", "!", "@", ".."]**
**def interpretCashier(input):
     for i in input:
       if i ==".":
         return "Transaction"
       elif input.isdigit():
        return "PIN"
       if i in symbols:
            return "Password"**
**print(interpretCashier("24.59"))
print(interpretCashier("123456"))
print(interpretCashier("my$......$$w0rd"))**
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Complete your solution first. Then, if you want ideas for *improving* it, see codereview.stackexchnage.com.

Answer (score 0):

A few side-notes: PEP 8 likes variable names and function names to be snakecase, separated by an underscore for multiple words (although there are exceptions and so it is not enforced; also I realise your exercise gave you the name to use, to be fair).

Also, and much more important, avoid using keywords (`input` in your code above) as variable names, as this will cause you some very confusing issues.

The code below is one way to solve your issue:

```
import decimal

def interpret_cashier(string):
    if string.isdigit():
        return "PIN"
    try:
        decimal.Decimal(string)  # Try to convert into a decimal, if it succeeds return "Transaction"
        return "Transaction"
    except decimal.InvalidOperation:
        # Conversion didn't work, so string must contain other characters, so return "Password"
        return "Password"

print(interpret_cashier("24.59"))
print(interpret_cashier("123456"))
print(interpret_cashier("my$......$$w0rd"))
```